# How to draw graph from an array?

Tags: python, data-visualization

I'm trying to visualize frequency of imported from reports items in array using Python. I'm new to drawing graphs, so how to do it, using any module?

Comment: I guess you should tell us what you have tried till now. Haven't you ever read anything on internet regarding it?

Answer (score 1):

To draw graphs in python you need to do the following,

```
import matplotlib as plt
plt.plot(array_1,array_2)
plt.show()
```

I highly recommend checking out this [Matplotlib Docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/contents.html)